# How to get files with desired name in C# using Directory.Getfile?

Tags: c#

I am trying to obtain a file of name "fileName.wav" from the directory whose path has been specified im not able to get the desired function .. any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(
        @"D:\project\Benten_lat\BentenPj_000_20141124_final\Testing\DPCPlus\Ref\Generated_Ref_Outputs_MSVS", "*.wav");

    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        string[] fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(
            @"D:\project\older versions\dpc_latest\Testing\DPCPlus\input");

        foreach (string  fileName1 in fileEntries1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(fileName1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Your code reminds me [for if anit-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx)

Comment: Getting files from path that is not direcotry is not good idea...

Comment: You know the directory, you know the file name. Why not just read/play it directly?

Comment: string[] fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\project\Benten_lat\BentenPj_000_20141124_final\Testing\DPCPlus\Ref\Generated_Ref_Outputs_MSVS\filename.wav"); what are you doing here. Getting files from file?

Comment: Define the use of the word obtain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Code will search for all `.xml` extension files with matches `abCd` name from `C:\\SomeDir\\` folder.

```
string cCId ="abCd";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\SomeDir\\");
FileInfo[] orderFiles = di.GetFiles("*" + cCId + "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

You should change this code according to your needs.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract name and extension from a file-path, you can use following code:

```
string result = Path.GetFileName(yourFilePath); // result will be filename.wav
```

---

You can not use `GetFiles` method for a file path!

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\project\Benten_lat\BentenPj_000_20141124_final\Testing\DPCPlus\Ref\Generated_Ref_Outputs_MSVS\filename.wav") //Error
```

The input for this method should be a directory!

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions based on your question (please correct me if I am wrong):

- You know the folder (e.g. the user entered it)
- You know the file name (e.g. it is hard coded because it must be the same always)

In this case you do not really need to search the file.

Solution:

```
string folderPath = @"D:\somewhere";
string fileName = "file.wav";
string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    // continue reading the file, etc.
}
else
{
    // handle file not found
}
```